# Php unable to retrieve dynamic generated textfields

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was unable to retrieve the dynamic generated textfields and radio buttons that I created using javascript but was able to retrieve the those that I manually added into the form using html.

Previously, I use styling to hide and show all my textfields instead of dynamically created textfields, so I have no problem getting all the textfields and can safely assume my PHP processing doesn't have any problem.

My HTML/Interface coding

```
<?php
for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++)
{
    $inputAreaID = "inputArea".$x;// Creating all dynamic options and etc in this div using javascript 
    $typeID = "type".$x; //for select type id
    $opt2ID = "ans".$x; 
    $optID = "opt".$x; 
    $comID = "com".$x; 
    $qnName = "qn".$x // for qn textfield name?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Question <?php echo $x ?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name='<?php echo $qnName ?>' required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Question Type</td>
        <td>
        <select id="<?php echo $typeID ?>" name="<?php echo $typeID ?>" onclick="showQuestionSelect('<?php echo $x ?>', '<?php echo $typeID ?>', '<?php echo $inputAreaID ?>')">
        <option value="">Please select one option </option>                 
            <option value="Yes,No">Yes/No </option>
            <option value="True,False">True/False</option>
            <option value="3">A. B. C. D.</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>   
        <div id='<?php echo $inputAreaID ?>' style="margin-bottom: 1px;margin-top:1px;"></div>
```

JavaScript coding

```
function showQuestionSelect(questionNo, typeID, inputArea) 
{
var s = String(typeID);
var i = String(inputArea);
var e = document.getElementById(s);
var selectedOpt = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

ansID = questionNo + "_ans";
comID = questionNo + "_com";
optA = questionNo + "_optA";
optB = questionNo + "_optB";
optC = questionNo + "_optC";
optD = questionNo + "_optD";

var msg = "";


if (selectedOpt == "True,False")
{
    msg ="<div style='margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top:10px;'><input type='radio' name='"+ ansID + "' value='True'> Submit True as Answer<input type='radio' name='" +ansID +"' value='False'> Submit False as Answer</div>";     
    msg +="<div style='margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top:10px;'>Reason for the answer: <input type='text' name='" + comID + "' value='' /></div>"
}
else if (selectedOpt == 3)
{
    msg = "<div style='margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top:10px;'>";
    msg += "Option A: <input type='text' name='" + optA + "' value='' /> <input type='radio' name='" + ansID + "' value='" + optA + "'> Submit as Answer  <br><br>";
    msg += "Option B: <input type='text' name='" + optB + "' value='' /> <input type='radio' name='" + ansID + "' value='" + optB + "'> Submit as Answer  <br><br>";
    msg += "Option C: <input type='text' name='" + optC + "' value='' /> <input type='radio' name='" + ansID + "' value='" + optC + "'> Submit as Answer  <br><br>";
    msg += "Option D: <input type='text' name='" + optD + "' value='' /> <input type='radio' name='" + ansID + "' value='" + optD + "'> Submit as Answer  </div>";      
    msg +="<div style='margin-bottom: 10px;'>Reason for the answer: <input type='text' name='" + comID + "' value='' /></div>";
}

document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = msg;

}
```

PHP Processing Coding

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++)
{
    $qn = $_POST["qn".$x]; // for qn textfield name
    $type = $_POST["type".$x]; //for select type id
    $ans = $_POST[$x."_ans"]; //for answer div id
    $reason = $_POST[$x."_com"]; //for answer div id

    $optionType = "";//to put into database

    if ($type == "Yes,No")
    {
        $ans = "";
        $reason = "";
    }

    if ($type == "3")
    {
        $optA = $_POST[$x."_optA"];
        $optB = $_POST[$x."_optB"];
        $optC = $_POST[$x."_optC"];
        $optD = $_POST[$x."_optD"];

        $optionType = $optA.",".$optB.",".$optC.",".$optD;

        if ($ans == $x."_optA")
            $ans = $optA;
        else if ($ans == $x."_optB")
            $ans = $optB;
        else if ($ans == $x."_optC")

        $ans = $optC;
        else 
            $ans = $optD;
    }
    else
        $optionType = $type;
```

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should to check server has got the values of those generated textfields. Try to display all members of `$_POST[]`.

I guess that you are stuck in the names of the parameters

Comment: I have echo out my $_POST[]; But i didn't put it in the code above. I have tested using the name by hardcoding my html name and creating "test textfield" that hardcode the names of dynamic generated test in gui files. The result is able to get retrieve with my processing php coding. 

I am using innerhtml to generate out my textfields. Does that affect whether I able to retrieve dynamic generated textfields?